# Doctrine2 Zend many-to-many relationship issue

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, database-relations

I have a many to many relationship set up between listings and categories. I am trying to set the categories for a listing using $listing->setCategories($categories). I do not get errors but the relationship isn't saved to the db.

I will include all of the relevant code below.

Mapping Files

Listing Mapping

```
<many-to-many field="categories" target-entity="Default_Model_Category" mapped-by="listings" >
     <cascade>
         <cascade-persist/>
     </cascade>
 </many-to-many>
```

Categrory mapping

```
 <many-to-many field="listings" target-entity="Default_Model_Listing" inversed-by="categories"/>
```

I have all the relevant variables and get/set functions in the model files.

trying to save the relationship in the controller.

```
    $catModel = $this->em->getRepository('Default_Model_Category');
    $catArray = array();
    foreach($categories as $single) {
       $catArray[] = $catModel->findOneById($single);
    }
    $listing->setCategories($catArray);
    $this->em->flush();
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a similar bug. I don't know what was causing it, but I had to save an empty array of values before saving the new relationships:

eg:

```
$listing->setCategories(array()); //clear current relationships
$this->em->flush();
$listing->setCategories($catArray); // save new relationships
$this->em->flush();
```

[edit]

It looks like you are assigning parent categories to a child listing. In simple terms, Doctrine is saying that the parent is right and the child is wrong so the child listing cannot assign a new parent. Try reversing the code?

```
$catModel = $this->em->getRepository('Default_Model_Category');
foreach($categories as $single) {
    $cat = $catModel->findOneById($single);
    $listingArray = $cat->getListings();
    $listingArray[] = $listing;
    $cat->setListings($listingArray);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

Comment: thanks. I had tried this already but I must have made a mistake somewhere. :)